# Mensagem de "referência indefinida para `itoa' " ao tentar usar função itoia

Tags: c, gcc

Encontrei em alguns sites pessoas falado do uso da função itoa para converter um numero inteiro em uma string contendo o número em formato binário.

## Exemplo de Código que deveria fazer isso:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

 int i = 5; // Valor a ser convertido
 char c[33]; // Onde vou guardar o valor convertido (use o tamanho 33)

 itoa(i, c, 2);  // converter na base 2, acredito que converta até base 32

 printf("%s\n", c);

 getchar();
}
```

Minha intenção erra fazer testes para ver os resultados das conversões antes de usar no meu programa porem ao tentar copilar recebo a mensagem :

[image: Mensagem que recebo ao tentar copilar o código.]

Logo de cara achei que o define com o Head file que continha o protótipo da função estava faltando, mas segundo os sites que consultei ela se encontra na stdlib.h.

Já tentei adicionar algumas  biblioteca, pesquisar a mensagem de erro dentre outras coisas.

Como outros exemplos como o [dessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190229/where-is-the-itoa-function-in-linux) também apresentam um problema semelhante.

Alguém sabe me explicar porque o problema ocorre e como resolver ?
Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Tirado da resposta que vc mesmo linkou: _"itoa() is indeed non-standard, as mentioned by several helpful commenters, it is best to use sprintf(target_string,"%d",source_int)"_ ou seja, não faz parte da especificação, entao nao é qualquer versão do compilador que vai ter. - teria alguma razão pra não usar o `snprintf` no lugar? Aqui tem um exemplo meio que "caseiro" para imprimir em binário: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3208376/916193 - O ideal no seu caso seria fazer uma função "binaryprint()" (ou qq coisa do tipo) própria, se quiser portabilidade. De qq forma vai ficar curtinha.

Comment: Não, não conhecia a função snprintf, estou olhando agora se me atende.

Comment: Já te adianto que não vai ter binário nativo, pesquise em "binário para decimal" aqui mesmo no site, que vai achar umas funções de exemplo. Basicamente é só ir dividindo o numero por dois e armazenando na string final como `bit[largurafinal - posicao] = '0' + (valor & 1)`

Comment: Consegui criar uma solução melhor e mais adequada para meu problema. Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Se for aplicável ao que perguntou, pode postar abaixo como resposta.

Comment: Não é, é um pouco descontextualizado do que perguntei aqui. Precisava disso pra resolver um problema maior. Abstraindo um pouco a ideia era testas todas as possibilidades possíveis pra um vetor de N itens. Assim pegava um inteiro que ia de 0  a N, e a cada iteração transformava esse número em binário para acessar uma das n combinação possíveis da minha estrutura de dados.